# Trying to add Data in the table

Tags: c#, winforms

I am Using MS Access DataBase.
I am trying to add Data in the table, But After adding a column id AutoNumber in the table. it gives an error. Please Guide me How I can solve this.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection sc = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand sm = new OleDbCommand("insert into prod values('" + textBox13.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" + textBox10.Text + "','" + textBox11.Text + "','" + textBox12.Text + "')", sc);
            //SqlCommand sm = new SqlCommand("insert into prod values(N'" + textBox1.Text + "',N'" + textBox2.Text + "',N'" + textBox3.Text + "',N'" + textBox4.Text + "',N'" + textBox5.Text + "',N'" + textBox6.Text + "',N'" + textBox7.Text + "',N'" + textBox8.Text + "',N'" + textBox9.Text + "',N'" + textBox10.Text + "',N'" + textBox11.Text + "',N'" + textBox12.Text + "',N'" + textBox13.Text + "')", sc);
            sc.Open();
            sm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //sm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sc.Close();
}
```

**Error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.**

Answer (score 1):

Always uses parameters to properly type data for inserts, updates, deletes and select/where.

Example

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AccessSamples
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var (exception, identifier) = DataOperations.Add(
                "New company", 
                "Some contact", 
                DateTime.Now);

            if (exception is null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"New id {identifier}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class DataOperations
    {
        private static string _connectionString => 
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=NorthWind.accdb";

        public static (Exception exception, int identifier) Add(string companyName, string contactName, DateTime modified)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var cn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = _connectionString })
                {
                    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand { Connection = cn })
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers (CompanyName,ContactName,Modified) " + 
                                          "VALUES (@CompanyName,@ContactName,@Modified)";
                        
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@CompanyName", OleDbType.LongVarChar));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ContactName", OleDbType.LongVarChar));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Modified", OleDbType.Date));

                        cmd.Parameters["@CompanyName"].Value = companyName;
                        cmd.Parameters["@ContactName"].Value = contactName;
                        cmd.Parameters["@Modified"].Value = modified;

                        cn.Open();

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@Identity";

                        return (null, Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return (ex, -1);
            }
        }

    }
}
```